# How to import dygraphs namespace

Tags: typescript, dygraphs

I'm trying to use Dygraph in Typescript. Its types are declared [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/dygraphs/index.d.ts).

I can't work out how to use the `clickCallback` option:

```
import Dygraphs from 'dygraphs';

...

    new Dygraph('el', data, {
      clickCallback: (e: MouseEvent, xval: number, points: dygraphs.Point[]) => {
         ...
      }
    });
```

This does not work because I cannot import the `dygraphs.Point` type. I've tried many variations of the `import` syntax (why the hell is importing something so complicated?) but nothing works. Is the problem that the `dygraphs` namespace is declared but not exported? Is this just a bug in the types?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not sure why but the exact same code is working for me now. All you need is

```
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
```

and you get the `Dygraph` object and also the `dygraphs` namespace. So just try quitting everything, restart your computer, etc.